# Can't align items in header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align items in my header but can't seem to get them to the way I want. I've tried using `float:right;` etc. but can't get them to align the way I have it in this image:

[image]

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Legion87/g8LLxz7h/

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="header-left">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-right">
            <div class="top-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="design.html">Design</a></li>
                    <li><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sign-ligin-btns">
            <ul>
                <li id="signupContainer"><a class="signup" id="signupButton" href="#"><span><i>Signup</i></span></a>
                <!-- Login Ends Here -->
                </li>
                <li id="loginContainer"><a class="login" id="loginButton" href="#"><span><i>Login</i></span></a>
                ...
```

Comment: Please don't down vote me. It's my first question so tell me what I've done wrong please so I don't do it again. @Tom-Sarduy Thanks for fixing it. I see what I've done wrong.

Comment: Try to be more clear and detailed as possible when you ask a question, anyway, I didn't down voted this question, I know the first question is hard :)

Comment: @Tom-Sarduy Didn't mean you did was just meant in general.

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen That's nearly it but I was trying to get the login/sign up above the menu. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body {
    background:#fff;
    font-family:'arial';
}
/*---start-wrap-----*/
 .wrap {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#page {
    display:none;
}
/*---start-header----*/
#header {
    padding: 0.3em 0 0em;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.header-left {
    float: left;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.logo a {
    color: #E95393;
    font-family:'arial';
    font-size: 35px;
}
.header-right {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
.top-nav {
    text-align:center;
}
.top-nav ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid #E95393;
    display:inline-block;
}
.top-nav ul li a {
    color: #43C5E6;
    padding: 1.8em 0.8em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition:0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition:0.5s all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s all;
    -o-transition:0.5s all;
}
.top-nav ul li a:hover {
    color:#E95393;
}
.top-nav {
    float:left;
}
#sign-ligin-btns {
    margin-left:25%;;
    margin-right:65%:
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li {
    display:inline-block;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li a.signup span, #sign-ligin-btns ul li a.login span {
    padding: 0.5em 1.8em 0.55em 1.8em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
    -o-transition: 0.5s all;
    border-radius: 0.15em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.15em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.15em;
    -o-border-radius: 0.15em;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li a.signup {
    color:#000;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li a.signup:hover {
    background: #43C5E6;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li a.login {
    color:#000;
}
#sign-ligin-btns ul li a.login:hover {
    background: #43C5E6;
}
/*---End-header----*/
```

```html
<div id="sign-ligin-btns">
  <ul>
    <li id="signupContainer"><a class="signup" id="signupButton" href="#"><span><i>Signup</i></span></a>

      <!-- Login Ends Here -->
    </li>
    <li id="loginContainer"><a class="login" id="loginButton" href="#"><span><i>Login</i></span></a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="header-left">
      <div class="logo"> <a href="index.html">Home</a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <div class="top-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="about.html">About</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="design.html">Design</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="store.html">Store</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen I realize I have the wrap @ 70% it should be 100%

Comment: My bad it is now. Maybe jsfiddle was overloaded.

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen First off thanks for the help. Secondly, unfortunately when I add the code to what I have it doesn't come out the way it does in your answer and I can't seem to figure out why...

Comment: Post an image or something

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen I did, not sure why it's happening. Here's an image http://i.imgur.com/N4MM4Uk.png

Comment: post a fiddle of the code you are using it looks like you haven't changed the signin btns to an id

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen Also here's a fiddle with my code in entirety http://jsfiddle.net/Legion87/js2butjo/

Comment: first you have logo as an id, it should be a class, also remove the float:left from loginContainer and signincontainer http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/js2butjo/2/ thats a start

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/js2butjo/4/ remove the position:relative form the login and sigin containers  http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/js2butjo/4/embedded/result/

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen Great thanks for the advice and help.

Comment: @Rachel-Gallen Just saw the new fiddle. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to go in detail, but how I should fix it:

1. Make one container div, set an `overflow: hidden` css-attribute to
   it.
2. In that container two other divs, the left div is say 30% wide, the
   right 60%.
3. The left div floats left, the right floats right
4. In the left div goes the logo
5. The right div gets two more div's: one for the user-related links,
   and one for the main menu
6. Both menu's are unordered lists
7. Each list item (li), has the CSS attribute `display: inline-block`
   or just `inline`.

By now you should be real close to what you want to achieve, you just may be there already as well. You can do this with a minimum of code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. That's kind of what I was trying to do but I think my brain melted a little haha. Thank you!